# Two Php sql queries for avgs pull same result. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Like i said up top, I have two queries right here.

```
$avg = "SELECT avg(CASE WHEN Lasttrade = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Lasttrade END) FROM $month
         ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 25";


$avg = "SELECT avg(CASE WHEN Lasttrade = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Lasttrade END) FROM $month
         ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 5";
```

I run them at seperate times, using

```
$result = $db->query($avg) or die ("avg t1 ");
```

but they pull the same results. I want to pull the avg of the last 5, and the last 25. But i get the same exact number. any thoughts?

Comment: How many records do you have in your database?

Comment: Your `LIMIT` is on your _total resultset_ which is only 1 row, as you are totalling the entire table if you omit any `GROUP BY`. You may want a _subquery_ with the `LIMIT`, and an outer query with an `AVG()`.

Comment: 120-140 tables in total. with 50-60 rows in each, 5 columns or so total

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` only limits the number of rows returned to you from your query. It does not limit the rows used in the query/calculations. You need to use a `WHERE` clause or subquery for that (depending on what you need exactly).

Comment: i want the last 5, last 10

Comment: See @Wrikken's comment above for how to do that

Answer (score 0):

John pointed out the 'why' already, `LIMIT` acts on the result set, not the query process, but here is how you need to do this, limiting the records to be averaged via subquery:

```
    SELECT avg(CASE WHEN Lasttrade = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Lasttrade END) 
    FROM (SELECT *              FROM $month
          ORDER BY ID DESC 
          LIMIT 0, 25") AS sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning one row because it is an aggregation query.  The `limit` is the last logical step in query processing -- after aggregation and the order by clause.

Try using a subquery to limit the number of rows:

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN Lasttrade <> 0 THEN Lasttrade END)
FROM (select m.*
      from $month m
      ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 25
     ) m
```